# Audio CDs will not Auto-mount Correctly

Tags: 10.10, sound, mount, cd, automount

When I try to play any audio CD in Ubuntu 10.10 the following message appears.
[image: Error message screen]

What is causing this problem with mounting an audio CD in the Ubuntu environment ?

I need to resolve this issue because I am trying to rip a couple of CDs, and I would like to see how it goes in Ubuntu 10.10.

Thank you in advance for support :)

Comment: This may sound stupid but have you tried rebooting? This fixed a (different) DBus timeout error for me.

Comment: Thank you for comments. But rebooting Ubuntu doesn't help. I think it is something deeper than just a time out issue.

Comment: Observation: Yesterday I boot my laptop using http://puppylinux.org/. Even live cd version allowed me to rip an audio CD without any probs :)

Comment: I would guess that one of the dbus processes has crashed.  If you look in the `~/.xsession-errors` you may see a clue.

Comment: Problem is, that you really can't mount Audio CD as you can mount data CD. Audio CD can only be detected by media players. In windows you can see some files on Audio CD, but you can't really manipulate them as normal files.

Comment: Hello ! I understand your point. I was thinking of simple play audio cd dialog when I insert an audio disk :) Probably, it's an issue of incorrect processing of 'audio cd in tray' situation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my issue has been resolved after entire set of system updates (I am speaking of 10.10). Now Rhythmbox is playing Audio CDs, so mounting process is OK. I just can give a basic info on my system (iCore 3 (M350), Ubuntu 10.10, kernel 2.6.35-28-generic-pae, Gnome 2.32.0, Rhythmbox v. 0.13.1.)
So thank you for comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this applies to you, but I had problems with audio CDs being recognised by some programs using a USB optical drive.

The problem programs were using udev to detect the details of the disc, and it seems that the cdrom_id helper that udev uses was generating larger SCSI commands than the drive could handle.  Since the program didn't add the udev attributes marking the disc as an audio CD, some programs would ignore the disc.

You can test if this affects you by running "/lib/udev/cdrom_id --debug /dev/cdrom".  If your drive is affected, the output will be something like:

```
main: probing: '/dev/cdrom'
cd_inquiry: INQUIRY: [CHIYOMI ][TSD80Y1 DVD RW  ][D010]
info_scsi_cmd_err: GET CONFIGURATION failed
ID_CDROM=1
ID_CDROM_CD_R=1
ID_CDROM_CD_RW=1
ID_CDROM_DVD=1
ID_CDROM_DVD_R=1
ID_CDROM_MRW=1
ID_CDROM_MRW_W=1
ID_CDROM_MEDIA=1
```

If the program is functioning correctly, then there should be more debug messages at the start and a few extra attributes similar to the following:

```
ID_CDROM_MEDIA_CD=1
ID_CDROM_MEDIA_SESSION_COUNT=1
ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT=16
ID_CDROM_MEDIA_TRACK_COUNT_AUDIO=16
```

If this describes the problem you're seeing, you could try replacing the /lib/udev/cdrom_id program with the version from natty as a work around.

Comment: Dear James. After many regular Ubuntu 10.10 updates I found that my system now is playing Audio CDs in Rhythmbox and in Banshee. Ripping feature (in ogg format) in Rhythmbox is also working.

Answer (score 0):

Original Author has commented with:

> I found that VLC is able to play Audio CDs. I found on Ubuntu forum that it is necessary to reinstall 'gvfs-backends'. So I did it. But I am not sure if this action has something with playing an Audio CD in VLC :)